# List the website pages that are using a specific JS File

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

**Purpose**: To understand what web pages have imported a **.js file** that I have written. 
Is there any way to inject a script into my .js file so that I can collect information about the sites ( at least domain name)?

e.g 
an X Site, https://www.x-site.com, has this import on its HP.html where I have **NO** access to.

```
<script src="https://domain.co/common-files/js/startup.js"></script>
```

And I want this **startup.js** file to somehow notify me that the **x-site.com** has been benefiting from itself.

The first thought in my mind is that I can simply **make GET requests** inside that JS file, with a parameter to another HTML file that my server hosts.

What do you think the best practice for that would be?

**PS**: I have no access to the server hosting the JS file since the platform I use is a CMS where I can simply load the assets including the aforementioned JS file.

**PS2**: I have no access to the websites that use this JS file either.

Comment: You might want to checkout Google Analytics API. Btw Adblocker might catch your requests.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, where the code in the body tag could be in your startup.js:

```js
<html>
<head>
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.js"></script>
    <script src="https://domain.co/common-files/js/startup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        var src = scripts[i]['src'];
        if (src && src.indexOf('https://domain.co/common-files/js/startup.js')>-1) {
            // track.php is a empty js file
            document.write('<script src="https://domain.co/track.php?siteUsingMyJs=');
            document.write(window.location.href);
            document.write('"><\/script>');
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most robust solution would be to configure your servers' access logs to track who is downloading your script file.

Look at [this Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html#accesslog), for example. It outlines how to make custom conditional log files.